# Skyepub on swift2 showing blank page

Tags: ios, swift, skyepub

I am implementing an ePub reader on iOs in swift2 with Skyepub.
I downloaded the SDK and Sample. Created a project with just a single ViewController.

On the ViewDidLoad i made a call to makeBookViewer

```
    var fileName: String
    fileName = "Alice-e.epub"
    self.makeBookViewer(fileName)
```

which is copied from the sample app and converted to swift.

```
func makeBookViewer(fileName: String) {

print("BaseDirectory: \(self.getBaseDirectory())")

let rv = ReflowableViewController(startPagePositionInBook:0.0)
rv.book.isFixedLayout = false
rv.book.fontSize = 12
rv.book.fileName = fileName
rv.book.bookCode = 123456
rv.baseDirectory = self.getBaseDirectory()
rv.transitionType = 0
rv.useDOMHighlight(false)
if self.isPad() {
    rv.setVerticalGapRatio(0.17)
}
else {
    rv.setVerticalGapRatio(0.20)
}
rv.setHorizontalGapRatio(0.3)
rv.setGlobalPaging(true)
rv.showIndicatorWhileLoadingChapter(false)
rv.showIndicatorWhilePaging(false)
rv.showIndicatorWhileRotating(true)
rv.allowPageTransitionFast(true)
rv.setCustomDrawHighlight(true)

rv.dataSource = self
rv.delegate = self

let skyProvider: SkyProvider = SkyProvider()
skyProvider.dataSource = self
skyProvider.book = rv.book
rv.setContentProvider(skyProvider)
rv.setGlobalOffset(true)
rv.setDrawingHighlightOnFront(false)

self.addChildViewController(rv)
rv.view.frame = self.view.frame
rv.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
self.view!.addSubview(rv.view!)
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = true

}
```

The ViewController shows a blank white page showing watermark "Unlicensed". immediately an activity indicator is shown. Then nothing happens.

On the log i can see

```
BaseDirectory: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6727DD2E-38BE-40E1/data/Containers/Data/Application/185322CD-BCA8-467B/Documents
2016-05-27 20:09:40.882 MyEPub[6296:175309] Application (null) Version 1 Copyrights (null)
2016-05-27 20:09:40.883 MyEPub[6296:175309] Application (null) Version 1 Copyrights (null)
2016-05-27 20:09:40.883 MyEPub[6296:175309] dealloc in Book
2016-05-27 20:09:40.884 MyEPub[6296:175309] destroy in Book
2016-05-27 20:09:40.884 MyEPub[6296:175309] processInit
2016-05-27 20:09:40.885 MyEPub[6296:175309] startServer 52326
2016-05-27 20:09:40.930 MyEPub[6296:175309] parseEncryption finished
2016-05-27 20:09:40.940 MyEPub[6296:175309] parseOpf Complete
2016-05-27 20:09:40.940 MyEPub[6296:175309] book parseXML finished
```

On the Skyepub sample the log further proceeds

I have copied the ePub file from Skyepub sample's book folder to BaseDirectory of mine. Can anyone give a hint what i have missed.

Comment: Im currently also using libskyepub.a but I cant access any objective-c in bridging header in swift. Can you tell me how you did it ?

Comment: i didn't get you really. if this is regarding bridging obj-c files into swift, then this may help you - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: no worries. I figured it out. I could not access any objective-c methods even though I imported all obj-c header because I forget to place all headers ( .h files) into my project.

Comment: hi can u please help me with sample code for swift.. I have no idea how to include the sdk and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create the view-controller in objective-c where I am using the skyepub book view. That solved the above issue.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain? Because if one has to use Obj-C then what's the point of converting the whole thing to swift?

Comment: we had problems while integrating skyepub obj-c library in swift2. we had to do above to solve it. don't know how it will be in latest versions, may be not relevant these days

Comment: Did you write the code to show the book viewer in obj-c or in swift? Is it like you created a VC in obj c and subclassed in swift?

Comment: We were developing a swift app. With Skyepub lib we need to add ReflowableViewController as child to a view controller which was first a swift class. The project was already bridged with Obj-C to add the Skyepub lib. Since it failed we tried the same in Obj-C view controller. And it worked. Please ask as I really don't get you. Are you about to suggest another way, as we shouldn't have to do like that. Happy to hear :-)

Comment: Can you share some code here how you did it? I tried something similar, didn't work out.

Comment: can you try adding the same view controller from the samples provided along with Skyepub lib. that should definitely work, right? what is the issue facing, blank page?

Comment: yes! Basically, our requirement is like, download the epub and then save it for viewing. Epub downloads, but what I see is blank screen or screen only showing the UNLICENSED watermark.

Comment: hi can u please help me with sample code for swift.. I have no idea how to include the sdk and use it

Answer (score 0):

make weak var like:

```
weak var weakself = self

rv.dataSource = weakself
rv.delegate = weakself

skyProvider.dataSource = weakself
```

maybe this can help you

Comment: hi can u please help me with sample code for swift.. I have no idea how to include the sdk and use it